# How to make changes to pseudo class in css using ng-class?

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I have a custom checkbox which I am styling using :before on the label of checkbox. Now I have a condition based on which I want to change the border color of the checkbox as red. I am not sure how I am supposed to do the same? Please find the class and html structure below:

```
<input id="tAndC" name="tAndC" type="checkbox"  class="paddingLeft" ng-checked= "card.acceptTC" required ng-model="card.acceptTC" ng-change="revertFocusOutTC()" ng-blur=""  >

                    <label for="tAndC" class="checkbox1 chkSmall chkTAndC marginLeft" ng-class="focusedOutTC?'checkboxErr':''">
```

CSS:

```
.checkbox1:before {
    content: "";
    display: inline-block;
    width: 24px;
    height: 24px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    background-color: transparent;
    color: #818181;
    text-align: center;
    border-color: #818181;
    border-radius: 2px;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-style: solid;
    float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this angular `ng-class` attribute in the following way:

`ng-class="{ checkboxErr : !!focusedOutTC }"`

**Explanation:** checkboxErr class name will be installed only if `Boolean` representation of `focusedOutTC` will equal `true`.

Answer (score 0):

put the class on the input instead and extend your css accordingly

```
<input ... class="{{ focusedOutTC ? 'checkboxErr':'' }}" ... />

.checkbox1:before {
   ...

   &.checkboxErr {
      border: 1px solid red !important;
   }

}
```

alternatively if you want to use ng-class you have to stick to the ng-class syntax, e.g.

```
ng-class="{ 'classname': condition }"
```

Answer (score 0):

two things come to mind. You could do :

```
.checkbox1:before {
    content: "";
    display: inline-block;
    width: 24px;
    height: 24px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    background-color: transparent;
    color: #818181;
    text-align: center;    
    border-radius: 2px;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-style: solid;
    float: left;
}
.grayBorder{
    border-color: #818181;
}
.redBorder{
    border-color: red;
}
                    <label for="tAndC" class="checkbox1 chkSmall chkTAndC marginLeft" ng-class="focusedOutTC?'grayBorder ':'redBorder">
```

Or you could always do

```
<label id="label1" for="tAndC" class="checkbox1 chkSmall chkTAndC marginLeft" ng-class="focusedOutTC?'grayBorder ':'redBorder">
```

... in JS

```
angular.element("#label1").addClass("redBorder");
angular.element("#label1").removeClass("redBorder");
```

you can also do angular.element("#id").css("border-color:red");

Comment: using jquery commands is not a very good tip, i would strongly recommend to avoid this as often as possible, if not ever. and this surely isn't a situation for addClass, removeClass or .css or any jquery selector whatsoever. if you want to use jquery in such situations you shouldn't use angular at all

Comment: Yea this guy is right. I'm still a  newb in angular and trying to train myself to think ng. The CSS I provided may help, but use the ng-class rather than jQuery anything.